# Uniformly convergent iterates for a function analytic on the complex unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

I have asked this question to several leading mathematicians in dynamical systems, and they all told me to ask someone else, until I was directed back to asking my advisor, with whom I first posed the question!...

I feel like this is probably in a textbook somewhere that I haven't read.

The Denjoy-Wolff theorem guarantees that, except for elliptic automorphisms, any analytic function on the open unit disk will have its iterates converge to a single point in the closed unit disk (the Denjoy Wolff point), uniformly so on compact subsets of the open unit disk.

Is there a complete characterization of functions from the open unit disk into itself whose iterates converge to their Denjoy-Wolff point uniformly on the -entire- open unit disk at once? An example would be f(z) = z/2 + 1/2, whose iterates converge to 1 uniformly on all of D.

I'm hoping that there is a characterization somewhere of all such analytic functions.

Thanks!

Comment: When the D-W point is in the open unit disk $D$, the necessary and sufficient condition is that $\overline{f^{n}(D)}\subset D$ for some $n$... which is admittedly not very explicit. The boundary case is more interesting though, and I've no clue there. [This user](http://mathoverflow.net/users/13360/mike-jury) might be the right person to ask, but he's not on Math.SE.

Comment: Thank you! I knew that if f is continuous on the boundary, then f_{n}(Dbar) would be sufficient. Do you know the proof of that version being both necessary and sufficient?